# Automatically hit a server every few seconds and receive data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, node.js, server

I have a local node.js server which has some new data every few seconds and also i have a iPhone app by using which right now i am able to get the JSON data from server and able to display it in my application.

But in current process user has to hit a option to get the data from server but i want to hit the server every 30 seconds automatically without user interaction and if any new data is there i want to get the data and display it.

So what is the best way to do this ?
Also is there any iOS Library is there which will help me to do this?

Comment: How about using websockets instead, sending the data from the server when it's actually available, no hitting neccessary

Comment: You could call whatever method starts your connection from an NSTimer's action method. You would want to make sure your users know this is happening, because it could use a lot of battery and cellular time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use websockets or other push technologies in a simple app that refreshes data every 30 seconds. But consider using [HTTP cache revalidation](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/) to reduce network traffic.

Use repeating NSTimer and make sure to [break retain cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821736/weak-reference-to-nstimer-target-to-prevent-retain-cycle).